# Is PerformanceTiming.responseStart points to HTML or headers start?

Tags: javascript, performance, web-performance

I have a question about [PerformanceTiming.responseStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/responseStart).

Is it a time to first byte of headers of a time to first byte of HTML? In some projects this times can be very different. E. g. when progressive page rendering is used.

Comment: `...first byte of the response from the server...` seems like the first byte, period, so probably the headers

Comment: And, there's also `PerformanceTiming.domLoading` for the exact moment the parser starts parsing HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] must return the time immediately after the user agent receives the first byte of the response from the server

http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-navigation-timing-20121217/#dom-performancetiming-responsestart

The Response is everything including the HTTP-Header, this is even before the HTML-Head. It's the moment when data is on the Networks Socket and beeing read for the first time.

Here is a neet little animation and explanation page about that: https://varvy.com/performance/responsestart.html

> When a resource is retrieved via the network (rather than the application cache) responseStart represents part of the HTTP request / response timeline.

It this Point in Time in your Browsers Network-Tool <kbd>F12</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: @dandavis `<head></head>` wich marks a point when other scripts in there start beeing loaded before the body is parsed. Wich is also an important point in time (and I think it was meant by the Questioineer as well).